# How To Upload a PHP Script Without Errors Being Thrown During Upload?

Tags: php, ftp

I have a rather interesting problem. I use FileZilla and Notepad++ to edit my PHP scripts. One script, called `functions.php`, is edited and changed a lot. Unfortunately, everytime I edit it and reupload it, I check my error log and find that about 5 errors were thrown across my site every time I reupload. It only takes a few seconds, but since the script is included in about every page on my website, that few seconds is enough to throw errors.

I was thinking that, perhaps, I could have a `functions2.php` that would be basically the same. Would there be a way for the scripts on my site to grab `functions2.php` if `functions.php` is not available? Thanks.

EDIT: The error I get is usually something like "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end..." which I believe implies that the script is just partially uploaded. This might make file_exists not the best solution, since the file is THERE but it is only 'halfway' there.

Uploading and renaming seems like a good solution, but it is a bit tedious for every upload :) I reupload and test a lot.

Is there a way to check a php file for PHP syntax errors? This would be quite handy in thise case...

Comment: upload as a diff name, then rename it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using FTP, consider a PHP / Perl / Ruby script that will take a POST of the file being uploaded, along with the file name and a MD5 / SHA of the file to be replaced (to make sure you have everything in the post). You need to add some security as well, such as behind an Apache Login.

Once the posted file is accepted by the PHP / Perl / Ruby script, the md5 checked (and the security passed too), the server will overwrite the "old" with the "new" version. This should be a lot quicker than FTP and reduce the errors.

Only possible issue is the file permission on the server will need to be set to allow write access from the web server.

Just an idea.

Another idea...

- Upload to a staging dir
- Login with ssh and perform `mv /staging/<file> ./`

You could have a cron job perform this once an hour too, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

1) Have code that grabs function2.php if function.php does not exist

See

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

and

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

```
<?php
if(file_exists('function.php')){
    require_once 'function.php';
}else{
    require_once 'function2.php';
}
?>
```

2) When you are updating the file, delete function.php, then upload the new file to newfile.php and then rename newfile.php to function.php

This way you won't get a half uploaded file being attempt to be fetched, and rename is very quick.

It's possible you could get an error between the file_exists and the require_once (if it exists then its deleted then it gets to the require_once and it no longer exists). But hopefully this won't happen as often, perhaps. At least, it will completely fail, if this happens, and they can reload the page. Maybe it won't happen.

Comment: This might be a bit far-fetched....but what if functions.php has a syntax error in it? Is there a way to grab functions2.php if functions.php has an error (assuming functions2 is clean).

Comment: using file_exists is a very bad idea here. The results are cached for many common webserver apis. So, the function will return true, yet the file doesnt exist. see the note in the documentation. even if this werent the case, your approach still introduces a race condition between checking for existence and using it.

Comment: Performing a `file_exists()` requires a file system check, which in turn makes a simple `require_once()` more expensive (as you are now performing an extra disk check). The other issue is you need to delete the older file - but which is older?